# new char [] vs new char(), delete() vs delete []

Tags: c++

What is the difference between:

```
int messageLen = 25;
char* message = new char [messageLen + 1];
```

```
int messageLen = 25;
char* message = new char (messageLen + 1);
```

and between:

```
delete(message);
```

```
delete [] message;
```

I read some articles on this topic, but none of them give me the exact answer.

I am beginner in C++, I'd be very grateful for some example!

Comment: `char* message = new char (messageLen + 1);` allocates a single character. `delete(message);` frees that single character.

Comment: Don't search for articles online, get [a good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: `char* message = new char [messageLen + 1];` allocates an array of 26 characters. `delete [] message;` frees the array.

Comment: Modern `c++` teaches you to avoid / almost never use `new`

Comment: std::string would be more appropriate most of the time over std::vector<char>

Comment: @drescherjm Why? When someone new would learn C++ a he doesn't know about `new` etc. I mean these hard stuff. why would anyone learn it then?

Comment: `new` is not a beginner concept. It's more of an advanced concept that is not easy to get correct. And modern `c++` nearly completely removes the need to ever use `new`. Its better for students to learn how to write quality `c++` code first then perhaps in an advanced course learn the ugly details of how it all works internally.

Comment: @JohnDoe `new` and `delete` do exist, and can be used, but for more complex projets, it leads to bugs or memory leaks because of the difficulty to track the usage of the allocated memory. Raw arrays are still useful in some cases, eg., interop with c (write code in c), interop with other languages (c#). However today, we should  use "initialization at declaration" and unique/managed pointers, that's the canonical modern c++. My opinion is that learning all the possibilities is the way to learn and understand.

Answer (score 3):

> What is the difference between:
>
> `int messageLen = 25; char* message = new char [messageLen + 1];`

This allocates a `char` array of 26, normally for 25 characters and a trailing `\0`.

> `int messageLen = 25; char* message = new char (messageLen + 1);`

Allocates a *single* `char` and gives it the value 26.

> `delete(message);`
>
> `delete [] message;`

`delete[]` frees memory allocated by `new[]`, `delete` (w/o `[]`) does the same for memory allocated by `new`; for efficiency, C++ doesn't keep track of this itself.

> I read some articles on this topic, but none of them give me the exact answer.

It sounds like you may need a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

> **I am beginner in C++**, I'd be very grateful for some example!

All of the above is now considered fairly advanced C++, "beginners" shouldn't concern themselves with it *at all*.  There are very few reasons to use `new`/`delete` and/or `new[]`/`delete[]`; avoid them unless you *really* know what you're doing.

The easiest way to deal with string data is to use `std::string`.  If you really need an array, look to `std::array` or `std::vector`.

```
 constexpr size_t messageLen = 25;
 std::array<char, messageLen+1> message;
```

---

If you *don't* have `std::string` or `std::vector`, are you sure you're *really* writing C++ code? Probably not (*C with classes*?).  Although `std::array` was added in C++11, so some really old environments may not have that.

But even then, reasonable facsimiles of these components can be written which *still* avoids the use of `new`, et. al. in normal client code.